# How to solve a given differential equation of form $\frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)^n\right)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We have a differential equation of the form $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)^n\right)=f(nx).$$ By inspection we have $f(x)=\sin(x)$ for $n=2$. Are there any other solution?

Comment: So, you are seeking solution to $$f'(x)=\frac{f(nx)}{nf(x)^{n-1}}$$?

Comment: @PrachurjyaBiswas is there a reason for your choice of notation?

Comment: I could'nt get you.

Comment: Yes it is right.

Comment: For $n=1$ you would get $f(x)=e^x$, but I assume you are wondering about higher values for $n$.

Comment: Yes. More than 2 or even 1

Comment: $e^{x/n}$ is obviously a solution for any value of $n$.

Comment: no. it is only true for $n = 1$

Comment: For $n=3$ you get $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2x}{\sqrt{3}}}$, so until now it does not seem to be any pattern in the solutions.

Comment: Also note that if we substitute $y = \ln x$ and $m = \ln n$, this turns into a non-linear delay-differential equation:$$\frac{d}{dy} \left(f(y)^{e^m}\right) = e^y f(y + m).$$  But I don't know nearly enough about delay-differential equations to know whether this new equation is remotely soluble.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I found that $f(x) = a x^b$ can be solved, when $n\neq1$, namely

$$
f'(x) = a b x^{b-1},
$$

$$
\frac{f(nx)}{nf(x)^{n-1}} = \frac{a n^b x^b}{n a^{n-1} x^{b(n-1)}} = a^{2-n} n^{b-1} x^{b(2-n)}.
$$

The powers of $x$ and the gains have to be the same, so

$$
b-1 = b(2-n) \to b = \frac{1}{n-1}
$$

$$
a b = a^{2-n} n^{b-1} \to a = \sqrt[n-1]{(n-1) n^{\frac{2-n}{n-1}}}.
$$

Thus the function as a function of $n$ can be written as

$$
f_n(x) = \sqrt[n-1]{(n-1)n^{\frac{2-n}{n-1}}x},
$$

but note that for this general solution I only used the "first" solution for $a$, when taking the $(n-1)$th root.

This general formula for the function gives $f_2(x) = x$, which differs from the OP solution of $f_2(x) = \sin{x}$, but that is probably because the differential equation is not causal, such that the initial conditions is not enough to find a particular solution also some information from the "future" is required.

Comment: Thank you. But can you just put a explanation for $f(x)=sin x$

Comment: Can't we have a pattern in this differential equation?

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment:  Let's look for a solution of the form $f(x) = C e^{\alpha x}$ for some (possibly complex) constants $\alpha$ and $C$.  Then we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ \left( C e^{\alpha x} \right)^n \right] &= C e^{\alpha (nx)} \\
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ C^n e^{\alpha n x} \right] &= C e^{\alpha nx} \\
C^n \alpha n e^{\alpha n x} &= C e^{\alpha n x} 
\end{align*}
which is satisfied if $C^{n-1} \alpha n = 1$, i.e., $f(x) = C e^{C^{1-n} x/n}$ for any constant $C$.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, this differential equation is non-causal for $n\neq1$, so I wonder how many general solution there are. Your solution does have a solution for $n=1$, and in that case the solution is causal, so should be unique (unless you would also consider multiplying by any constant).

Comment: @fibonatic:  Actually, it looks like one can generalize my solution by multiplying it by a pre-factor (in which case the exponent depends on that pre-factor.)  I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: I was more referring to solutions of total different forms; such as in mine answer, which is a power function. Might there be a periodic function for every $n\neq1$?

Comment: @fibonatic:  I would expect that there wouldn't be a periodic solution for non-integer $n$.  Integers, though — could be...

Comment: So there is no pattern in this kind of differential solution?